# Google Analytics: how can I track a click that redirects to an external url?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-analytics

I have a URL in my (Ruby on Rails)web application that links to an external page (iTunes app page) and I would like to track visits to that link. I'd also like to be able to track the `utm_campaign` variable so that I can see how many visits different campaigns are sending to this URL.  I don't think I can do a 301 redirect here, since Google Analytics is using JavaScript. How can I accomplish this?

EDIT: to be more specific, the URL is there to use in marketing materials (fliers, etc.). There isn't an actual link in the application.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you write some JS that captures the click event of the anchor, increments a counter, and then fires up the href of that anchor in another window (target="_blank")?

Comment: There is not a link to this URL in the application, so no, that will not work. I updated my question, I realize I worded it a bit confusingly.